# Reversing a linked list starting from the tail using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, linked-list, reverse

I still struggle with the recursion technique to solve the  problem. I know there are nicer ways to solve my problem below of reversing a linked list. Most of the ways that I have seen, start to reverse the pointers by going from the head to the tail, either by using iteration or recursion.

I am trying for interest to reverse the list by first finding the last node in the list recursively and then changing the pointers everytime the function returns.

What am I doing wrong below exactly? Or will this method even work , without the need to pass more parameters to the recursive function? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

Node* Reverse(Node *head)
{
    static Node* firstNode = head;
    // if no list return head
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return head;
    }

    Node* prev = NULL;
    Node* cur = head;

    // reached last node in the list, return head
    if (cur->next == NULL)
    {
        head = cur;
        return head;
    }

    prev = cur;
    cur = cur->next;
    Reverse(cur)->next = prev;

    if (cur == firstNode)
    {
        cur->next = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    return cur;
}
```

EDIT : Another attempt

```
Node* ReverseFromTail(Node* prev, Node* cur, Node** head);

Node* ReverseInit(Node** head)
{
    Node* newHead = ReverseFromTail(*head, *head, head);
    return newHead;
}



Node* ReverseFromTail(Node* prev, Node* cur, Node** head)
{
    static int counter = 0;
    counter++;

    // If not a valid list, return head
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return *head;
    }

    // Reached end of list, start reversing pointers
    if (cur->next == NULL)
    {
        *head = cur;
        return cur;
    }


    Node* retNode = ReverseFromTail(cur, cur->next, head);
    retNode->next = cur;


    // Just to force termination of recursion when it should. Not a permanent solution 
    if (counter == 3)
    {
        cur->next = NULL;
        return *head;
    }

    return retNode;
}
```

Finally Solved it :

```
Node* NewestReverseInit(Node* head)
{
    // Invalid List, return
    if (!head)
    {
        return head;
    }

    Node* headNode = NewestReverse(head, head, &head);

    return headNode;
}

Node* NewestReverse(Node *cur, Node* prev, Node** head)
{
    // reached last node in the list, set new head and return
    if (cur->next == NULL)
    {
        *head = cur;
        return cur;
    }

    NewestReverse(cur->next, cur, head)->next = cur;

    // Returned to the first node where cur = prev from initial call
    if (cur == prev)
    {
        cur->next = NULL;
        return *head;
    }

    return cur;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked for other questions on the topic?  The RHS "Related Questions" section lists several candidates; I doubt if that list is comprehensive.

Comment: But what is the problem? Please explain.

Comment: There is no prev in the struct.

Comment: It's just failing all the time. I can't get the logic correct using this method

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk , I know. there shouldn't be a prev struct member

Comment: If You have a ```next``` and ```prev``` You just have to iterate over the list and swap the ```next``` and ```prev``` pointers. And the head is the last element of the list.

Comment: Updated my answer. The clue is that You are mixing the *starting* call with the *recursion* call. Take it out to the a separate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full implementation I wrote in 5 minutes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node
{
     int data;
     struct Node *next;
};

struct Node* Reverse(struct Node *n)
{
    static struct Node *first = NULL;

    if(first == NULL)
      first = n;

    // reached last node in the list
    if (n->next == NULL)
      return n;

    Reverse(n->next)->next = n;

    if(n == first)
    {
      n->next = NULL;
      first = NULL;     
    }

    return n;
}

void linked_list_walk(struct Node* n)
{
  printf("%d", n->data);
  if(n->next)
    linked_list_walk(n->next);
  else
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  struct Node n[10];
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    n[i].data = i;
    n[i].next = n + i + 1;
  }
  n[9].next = NULL;

  linked_list_walk(n);
  Reverse(n);
  linked_list_walk(n+9);
}
```

Output:

```
0123456789                                                                                                                                                                          
9876543210
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw, removed comment.  Althought while you are checking, what does `Reverse(null)` do?

Comment: Static variables in recursive functions are seldom good idea.

Comment: @James Poag: I really don't understand the problem or the downvote. This works exactly as expected. I'm doing no error checking here since this is not the purpose of the q&a.

Comment: @SegeyA: Also irrelevant. The question was not about best practices but rather about how to accomplish something.

Comment: @James: Initially that was the only comment so I naturally assumed... my apologies.

Comment: @schwrz While I didn't downvote you, I didn't upvote either. I believe, in high standard of the code on SO answers, and yours do not meet the bar.

Comment: You are entitled to you opinion Sergey but it's obviously just silly since my answer is the closest to what the OP tried to accomplish while also working as expected.

Comment: @schwrz There is more to a good answer than providing a working solution. It should also take into account the background of the question, what they were trying to achieve and why they failed. In particular for beginner-level questions like this, just providing the source code is often counter-productive to this, as the goal of the answer should be to provide a better understanding of the problem and not just the solution. The answer by SergeyA acknowledges this.

Comment: @SergeyA , I agree with you. The question I asked was not to find the best practice to solve this issue, but rather how to accomplish it in a different way and to help me, and hopefully others on here think differently and improve their coding skills

Comment: @ComicSansMS I understand you POV but I personally think that newbs shouldn't be spoonfed. He (the OP) can see what he did wrong just by comparing his answer to mine. I went out of my way to make them similar for exactly that reason. I have tutored many beginner engineers and this method served me (and them) very well. Again, everyone is entitled to his\her opinion.

Comment: @Engineer999, judging by your comment you agree with ME and disagree with Sergey. 
FYI, The symbol @ means "at", the name of the commentator is at the end of the comment so it is I who commented *AT* James that this was not a q. about best practices. Just putting it out there.

Comment: @schwrz, yup sorry, I meant to agree with you )

Comment: @schwrz, thanks for the implementation, but how would you modify your Reverse function to return the new head of the reversed list. It currently doesn't

Comment: i was not aware that that is a requirement. in any case the solution is simple but - having been criticised - this time i will not provide source code but instead describe how to attack the problem. you already have the pointer to the head in a very appropriately named variable (hint hint). it is now just a question of *when* to return it. hint #2: it is very tempting at first glance to solve this by changing just one line. don't, as that will ruin you function's reusability (i.e. it will not work more than once). you'll need at least a couple more lines of code to fix this. good luck.

Comment: @schwrz . Look at my latest edit. I finally solved it :) . I also removed the undesired static variable and just use a separate function to set the initial state. I disagree with others saying you shouldn't be posting solutions here. It helped me understand how to solve the problem better. This I know is by no means the best way to solve this reversing list problem. The tail recursive way by going forward is maybe the best. I still however unfortunately struggle with using recursion to solve problems, even after years of programming, so it is why i'm trying random things to get a better grasp.

Answer (score 4):

I will not give you the code, I will give you the idea. You can implement the idea in the code.

The key to all recursion problems is to figure out two cases: repetition step and end case. Once you do this, it works almost as if magically.

Applying this principle to reversing a linked list:

- End case: the list of one element is already reversed (this is straightforward) and returning the element itself
- Repetition case: Given list L, reversing this least means reversing an L', where L' is the L' is the list without the very first element (usually called `head`), and than adding the head as the last element of the list. Return value would be the same as a return value of the recursive call you just made.

Comment: I understand the idea but still struggling with my particular method of implementation. Please see my code edit, a second attempt. It's driving me mad as I still can't see what is wrong. when trying to print the resulting list, only the head and tail seems to be there. Can you spot what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It can be done. The key in understanding recursion is *What is the starting point?*

Usually I create a *"starting"* function which prepares the first call. Sometimes it is a separate function (like in non OO implemnatation at bottom). Sometimes it's just a special first call (like in example below).

Also the key is in remembering variables before they change and what is the `new head`.

The new `head` is the last element of the list. So You have to get it up from the bottom of the list.

The `next`element is always your parent.

Then the trick is to do everything in the correct order.

```
    Node* Reverse( Node* parent) // Member function of Node.
    {
        Node* new_head = next ? next->Reverse( this ) 
                              : this;

        next = parent;

        return new_head;
    }
```

You call the function with: `var.Reverse( nullptr);`

Example:

```
int main()
{
    Node d{ 4, nullptr };
    Node c{ 3, &d };
    Node b{ 2, &c };
    Node a{ 1, &b };

    Node* reversed = a.Reverse( nullptr );
}
```

So what is happening here?

First we create a linked list:

```
 a->b->c->d->nullptr
```

Then the function calls:

1. `a.Reverse(nullptr)` is called.
2. This calls the `Reverse` on the next node `b.Reverse` with parent `a`.
3. This calls the `Reverse` on the next node `c.Reverse` with parent `b`.
4. This calls the `Reverse` on the next node `d.Reverse` with parent `c`.
5. `d` doesn't have `next` node so it says that the new head is itself.
6. `d`'s `next` is now it's parent `c`
7. `d` returns itself as the `new_head`.
8. Back to `c`: `new_head` returned from `d` is `d`
9. `c`'s `next` is now it's parent `b`
10. `c` returns the `new_head` it recieved from `d`
11. Back to `b`: `new_head` returned from `c` is `d`
12. `b`'s `next` is now it's parent `a`
13. `b` returns the `new_head` it recieved from `c`
14. Back to `a`: `new_head` returned from `b` is `d`
15. `a`'s `next` is now it's parent `nullptr`
16. `a` returns the `new_head` it recieved from `b`
17. `d` is returned

---

Non object oriented implementation;

```
Node* reverse_impl(Node* parent)
{
    Node* curr = parent->next;
    Node* next = curr->next;

    Node* new_head = next ? reverse_impl( curr ) 
                          : curr;

    curr->next = parent;

    return new_head;
}

Node* reverse(Node* start)
{
    if ( !start )
        return nullptr;

    Node* new_head = reverse_impl( start );
    start->next    = nullptr;

    return new_head;
}
```

Comment: Clever.  You can set `parent` default parameter to nullptr so the method call is cleaner.

Comment: Yea thanks. Already thought about that, but I'm afraid that it will not be as clear for everybody. (It would become the *starting* function I mention.)

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Please see my code edit, a second attempt. I still can't see what is wrong. When trying to print the resulting list, only the head and tail seems to be there. Can you see maybe what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: @Engineer999 Did You use a debugger to watch the variables, when stepping through the code?

Comment: @Engineer999 retNode is a bad name. What is it that is being returned? Give it a proper name so that You will be able to understand the logic that is programmed.

Comment: @Engineer999 1) the last return should be ```return cur;``` 2) ```ReverseInit``` doesn't get the ```newHead```. It's the ```lastElement``` which needs to set ```next``` to ```nulltptr```.